# What is this set of all sets one line function doing?

Tags: python, lambda, set, list-comprehension

I found this one line function on the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Powerful%20Python%20One-Liners) that creates a set of all sets that can be created from a list passed as an argument.

```
f = lambda x: [[y for j, y in enumerate(set(x)) if (i >> j) & 1] for i in range(2**len(set(x)))]
```

Can someone please explain how this function works?

Comment: I know how to run the function. I just don't understand how to code actually generates a set of all sets.

From what I already know, (i >> j) & 1 shifts the binary bits of i to the right J times, and then does a bitwitse and of i and 1.

I don't understand the relevance of all this to actually creating the resultant set though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct the powerset, iterating over `2**len(set(x))` gives you all the binary combinations of the set.

```
range(2**len(set(x))) == [00000, 00001, 00010, ..., 11110, 11111]
```

Now you just need to test if the bit is set in `i` to see if you need to include it in the set, e.g.:

```
>>> i = 0b10010
>>> [y for j, y in enumerate(range(5)) if (i >> j) & 1]
[1, 4]
```

Though I'm not sure how efficient it is given the call to `set(x)` for every iteration. There is a small hack that would avoid that:

```
f = lambda x: [[y for j, y in enumerate(s) if (i >> j) & 1] for s in [set(x)] for i in range(2**len(s))]
```

A couple of other forms using `itertools`:

```
import itertools as it
f1 = lambda x: [list(it.compress(s, i)) for s in [set(x)] for i in it.product((0,1), repeat=len(s))]
f2 = lambda x: list(it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(set(x), r) for r in range(len(set(x))+1)))
```

Note: this last one could just return an iterable vs list if you remove `list()` depending on the use-case this could save some memory.

Looking at some timings of a list of 25 random numbers 0-50:

```
%%timeit binary: 1 loop, best of 3: 20.1 s per loop
%%timeit binary+hack: 1 loop, best of 3: 17.9 s per loop
%%timeit compress/product: 1 loop, best of 3: 5.27 s per loop
%%timeit chain/combinations: 1 loop, best of 3: 659 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite it a bit and break it down step by step:

```
f = lambda x: [[y for j, y in enumerate(set(x)) if (i >> j) & 1] for i in range(2**len(set(x)))]
```

is equivalent to:

```
def f(x):
    n = len(set(x))
    sets = []
    for i in range(n): # all combinations of members of the set in binary
        set_i = []
        for j, y in enumerate(set(x)):
            if (i>>j) & 1: #check if bit nr j is set
                set_x.append(y)
        sets.append(set_i)
    return sets
```

for an input list like `[1,2,3,4]`, the following happens:

```
n=4
range(2**n)=[0,1,2,3...15]
```

which, in binary is:

```
0,1,10,11,100...1110,1111
```

Enumerate makes tuples of y with its index, so in our case:

```
[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

The `(i>>j) & 1` part might require some explanation.
`(i>>j)` shifts the number `i` `j` places to the right, e.g. in decimal: `4>>2=1`, or in binary:`100>>2=001`. The `&` is the bit-wise `and` operator. This checks, for every bit of both operands, if they are 1 and returns the result as a number, acting like a filter: `10111 & 11001 = 10101`.

In the case of our example, it checks if the bit at place `j` is 1. If it is, the corresponding value is added to the result list. This way the binary map of combinations is converted to a list of lists, which is returned.